# IFileOperation::DeleteItems doesn't ask for confirmation on Windows 8 (unlike Windows 7)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8

I'm experimenting with deleting files on Windows with `IFileOperation::DeleteItems`. On Windows 7, when I invoke IFileOperation::PerformOperations` I get a question asking whether I want to delete the files first. But on Windows 8 it doesn't ask for a confirmation and just moves files to trash.

This is the prompt I'm talking about:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
result = iOperation->DeleteItems(iArray);
if (SUCCEEDED(result))
{
   result = iOperation->SetOperationFlags(FOF_ALLOWUNDO);
   assert(SUCCEEDED(result));
   result = iOperation->SetOwnerWindow((HWND)parentWindow);
   assert(SUCCEEDED(result));
   result = iOperation->PerformOperations();
}
```

I've also tried `SetOperationFlags(FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE);` - the effect seems to be the same.

If I request a file to be deleted irrevocably instead of being moved to trash (`SetOperationFlags(FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING)`) I get a prompt just like in Windows 7.

How can I get deletion prompt on Windows 8?

Comment: Just to make sure, your Windows settings are the same on both systems? You didn't disable the confirmation dialogue on your Windows 8 system in the recycle bin properties window?

Comment: @hvd: Thanks a lot, that's it! I never noticed this option, and it seems to be disabled in Windows 8 by default. Please make it an answer so I can accept and upvote :)

Comment: Sure, glad it's that simple. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments:

Whether a confirmation is displayed is a user setting. It can be changed from the Properties window of the recycle bin. On your Windows 8 system, that option is disabled. On your Windows 7 system, that option is enabled. It may be, as you suggest, that the default value of this option has been changed in Windows 8, but you can still manually enable it.